# If a JS 6 module is imported in multiple modules on a page, is it's "main line" code executed only once?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, initialization

In JS 6, suppose I import module A both in module B and in Module C.
And suppose B and C are both loaded in module script tags in HTML.
Is the mainline code in A then executed only once?
Where can I find official doc on that? (Or a solid explanation).

Comment: provide more information on it

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Only once. The browser loads and executes module when it is imported. Next imports receive executed value. You can read more about modules here https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

If you use build tools, like webpack, they behave the same way (usually).